# Netbeans search for 2 terms per row

Tags: mysql, search, netbeans, myisam

Is there a way to search for 2 items with "Find in projects" - search or CTRL+F, for example, looking for table joins in a PHP source code:

```
LEFT JOIN table_name column_name ON another_table_name;
```

where I would like to look for **JOIN** and **table_name**. What I am trying to accomplish here is to look for table connections in Netbeans between MyISAM tables and reverse-engineer a database schema.

Syntax could be something like table_name +JOIN, or table_name AND JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Regular Expression and Try the below regex :

```
\bJOIN\b.*\btable_name\b|\btable_name\b.*\bJOIN\b
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/RQ5jmF/1

Explanation :

```
\b -> word boundary 
.* -> matches any character (except for line terminators) zero and unlimited times
```

Comment: Thank you! Java expressions is a new thing for me.